# Unexpected token o in JSON - node / API

Tags: node.js, json, api

When ran, I get an error saying:
undefined:1
[object Object]
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse ()

the code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get("/",function (req,res) {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html")
    
    app.use(express.static('public'));

})

app.post("/",function(req,res){

    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    const email = req.body.email;
    
    const data = {
        members:{
            email_address: email,
            status:"subscribed",
            merge_fields:{
                FNAME:firstName,
                LNAME:lastName
            }
        }
    }
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
const url = "https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/";
const options = {
    method:"POST",
    auth:"sudolake:api_key"
}
const request = https.request(url, options, function(response){
    response.on("data",function(){
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
})
   })


request.write(jsonData);
request.end();


})
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("the server is up & running");

})
```

I know its probably something with the "const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);" but I don't know what, its probably really stupid, thanks for any help

Comment: `data` is already an object in that `console.log` so you don't need to parse it again..  `jsonData` is that data in JSON, but you should just be able to use `data` directly.